# Do I need middleware like redux-thunk or saga? Angular-redux

Tags: angular, redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk

Hi I'm developing an Angular website. I used Angular build-in httpClient library to make backend call. It return an observable. So I subscribed that observable and dispatch straight from that observable with payload. Is it a good practice or do i need to use middle-ware like redux-thunk or saga. If so why? Here is how i do it in code.

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this.http.getProduct().subscribe((x) => {
        this.ngRedux.dispatch({ type: SET_PRODUCTS, payload: x })
      });
  }
```

Comment: Creating and dispatching an action to store after an asynchronous call completes(like HTTP response) is easy with thunk/saga. So recommended using some middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is built around RxJS [Observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables). RxJS is not a datastore like Redux, but rather a way to make your application reactive.

Getting the most out of Angular means fully embracing RxJS and incorporating related features such as [async pipes](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

Comment: Sir, thank you for your answer. I know Rxjs is not a data store like redux, and is not the question that I asked. The question that I’m trying to ask is do I need middleware like redux thunk and saga to do backend call or is it a good practice to set the redux state straight from observable.

Comment: Using redux at all is atypical in an Angular app. Not to say you couldn't do it, but you're unlikely to find much advice on how to incorporate it. Typically service classes make backend calls via HttpClient and return Observables that components subscribe to.